# EVENTVALIDATION error while scraping asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I need to get some values from this [website](http://www.uninor.in/UninorConnAssist/locate-a-store/Pages/locate-a-store.aspx). Basically I need to get the Area for every city. I am using Python and beautifulsoup for this. What I am doing is :

1. First making a Get request to this page and getting __VIEWSTATE AND __EVENTVALIDATION to make a POST request to get cities for a particular state.Till here its working and I am getting cities for every states.
2. To get Area I need to make another POST with new __VIEWSTATE AND __EVENTVALIDATION and this time i need to send city as well with other parameters.But I am getting error here:

> ```
> 505|error|500|Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation
> is enabled using <pages enableeventvalidation="true"> in configuration
> or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
> purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
> events originate from the server control that originally rendered
> them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
> ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
> register the postback or callback data for validation.|</pages>
> ```

I have checked each and every argument/parameter in firebug that I need to send to get areas for corresponding cities but no success. Maybe according to me problem is with __VIEWSTATE or __EVENTVALIDATION.

please help me

Comment: You shouldn't need to change ViewState on the client side.

Comment: i am not changing the __VIEWSTATE...i am grabbing it from the html returned by server

Comment: Are you posting back the values of ViewState and EventValidation? If not, then that's your problem right there: You must post back those variables back to the server because the server.

Comment: Are you sending cookies acquired with the first request?

Comment: @ArtemKoshelev I dont think cookies are required in this request. As i have get data for cities without sending cookies data.

Comment: @user1170793 how did you solved that?

Answer (score 1):

you have to get and pass the `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` variables in one session call, otherwise when doing the second POST call while reopening connection to the server it expects to receive back already another `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION`!

So basically the logics should be as follows:

- curl_init()
- curl GET __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION
- ***some logics here ***
- curl POST parsed out __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION
- *** some logics here ***
- curl_close();

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `__REQUESTDIGEST` form field, it is a validation field used by Sharepoint.
Also, add name of the select element with states as the value of `__EVENTTARGET` field:

```
__EVENTTARGET   ctl00$ctl25$g_4828177f_5427_4b0f_a968_ad02dc3674ec$ctl01$ddlState
__REQUESTDIGEST 0xDF6A6E14C550004C4A8533A9F5D...,14 Jun 2012 10:13:34 -0000
```

Comment: I am already sending these fields with my POST request, still no success :(