# Error while scraping website

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

i am trying to scrape a website using beautilfulsoup. But when i scrape it, i receive certain error

error i received is :

```
505|error|500|Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableeventvalidation="true"></pages> in configuration or &lt;%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %&gt; in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.|
```

and my codes are :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

final_data = []
url = "https://rera.cgstate.gov.in/Default.aspx"

def writefiles(alldata, filename):
    with open ("./"+ filename, "w") as csvfile:
        csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        csvfile.writerow("")
        for i in range(0, len(alldata)):
            csvfile.writerow(alldata[i])

def getbyGet(url, values):
    res = requests.get(url, data=values)
    text = res.text
    return text

def readHeaders():
    global url
    html = getbyGet(url, {})
    soup  = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    EVENTVALIDATION = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']
    VIEWSTATE = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
    #VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")[0]["value"]
    headers= {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
              'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0'}
    formfields = {"__ASYNCPOST":"true",
              "__EVENTARGUMENT":"",
              "__EVENTTARGET":"" ,
              "__EVENTVALIDATION":EVENTVALIDATION,  
              "__LASTFOCUS":"", 
              "__VIEWSTATE":VIEWSTATE,
              "ApplicantType":"",
              "Button1":"Search",
              "District_Name":"0",
              "DropDownList1":"0",
              "DropDownList2":"0",
              "DropDownList4":"0",
              "DropDownList5":"0",
              "group1":"on",
              "hdnSelectedOption":"0",
              "hdnSelectedOptionForContractor":"0",
              "Mobile":"",
              "Tehsil_Name":"0",
              "TextBox1":"",
              "TextBox2":"",
              "TextBox3":"",
              "TextBox4":"",
              "TextBox5":"",
              "TextBox6":"",
              "ToolkitScriptManager1":"appr1|Button1",
              "txt_otp":"", 
              "txt_proj_name":"",
              "txtRefNo":"",
              "txtRefNoForContractor":""}
    s = requests.session()
    res = s.post(url, data=formfields, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")
    print(soup)
readHeaders()
```

what am i doing wrong? can someone guide? i read another post with same error someone received but his post also didnt have any soultion. This is the post link [EVENTVALIDATION error while scraping asp.net page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030460/eventvalidation-error-while-scraping-asp-net-page?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Your provided url is Inaccessible.

Comment: It is working. It is opening here.Once it is opened , Go to reports > Approved projects/promoters or use this url https://rera.cgstate.gov.in/